# Where can I get sample JSON data to use in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, sample-data

What are some sources for sample data (preferably sanitized json)?  The intended use is to import into MongoDB for evaluating and demo apps.

Comment: Here is the repo for this. http://t.co/0RmlnedDWp

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check this one out http://media.mongodb.org/zips.json this is provided by mongodb

Comment: I found my GeoJSON file here that conforms to the specifications ie. GeoJSON object type and a coordinates field: http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.com/2014/08/introduction-to-mongodb-geospatial.html

Comment: I found https://www.fireboxtools.com/sample-data/json-examples. If you are looking for Sample JSON in many formats (for example, user data sample, product data sample, short JSON data, lengthy JSON data)